# HtmlAgilityPack sanitizing string issue

Tags: html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to sanitize user entered rich text and strip any harmful/unwanted text. Problem occurs though when a simple text is also treated as html node

If I enter

```
a<b, c>d
```

and try to sanitize it, the output generated is

```
 a<b, c="">d</b,>
```

The code I used was

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HthmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(value);
// Sanitizing Logic

var result = doc.DocumentNode.WriteTo();
```

I tried to set different parameters on HtmlDocument ('OptionCheckSyntax', 'OptionAutoCloseOnEnd', 'OptionWriteEmptyNodes') to not have the text be treated as a node but nothing worked. Is this is a known issue or any workaround possible?

Comment: What are you expecting for that input?

Comment: The same as input. The intention behind using HAP was to strip out tags like script/link/iframes and such. Is there anyway to not let HAP treat every '<' as start of new html node?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, there's no way you can tell HAP to not treat every '<' as start of new html node. But you can check if your html is a validate html or not by using

```
string html = "your-html";

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

if (doc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0)
{
   //here you can ignore or do whatever you want
}
```